# SQL Server displays empty resultset instead of Unicode characters after I changed collation

Tags: sql-server, unicode, collation, nvarchar

I created a table Tab with nvarchar(max) field Fld.
With default Latin collation the next code

```
update Tab set Fld = N'текст' where ID = 50

select Fld from Tab where ID = 50
```

It returns `????`

After I changed collation to Cyrillic SQL Server displays empty recordset.
Please help.

Comment: What tool are you using to get the results?  It may simply be a display issue, not a data issue.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio or Toad for SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

It looks fine. Sure you had the "N" in front of your quoted text value?

If I run the reproduction:

```
CREATE DATABASE [i18n_Latin1_General_CI_AS] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS;
GO

USE [i18n_Latin1_General_CI_AS];
CREATE TABLE [NLocations] ([Place] nvarchar(15) NOT NULL);  
GO  

INSERT [NLocations]([Place]) VALUES (N'текст');  
GO 

SELECT [Place] as [Order with Unicode and Latin1_General_CI_AS] FROM [NLocations] ORDER BY [Place] ASC;

USE [master];
GO

DROP DATABASE [i18n_Latin1_General_CI_AS];
GO
```

It returns:

[image]